# Ubuntu, jack, maximum priority for audio application

Tags: audio-jack, daw

**OS, apps and hardware info**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-23-lowlatency #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 29 16:17:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jackdmp version 1.9.12 tmpdir /dev/shm protocol 8
Bitwig-studio version 3.0.1
USB2 Audio interface Tascam US16x02
```

**Question**

Is possible run audio application with max priority for this application? For best performance and lowest latency without cruckling/buffer problem for audio application.

**Situation**

I reinstalled `Ubuntu studio 19.04`, `update`, `upgrade`, install DAW `Bitwig studio 3.0.1`, then install `indicator-cpufreq` (for changing my cpu to best performance).

Then I ran `jackd` in this configuration.

```
/usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:US16x08 -r44000 -p128 -n2
```

I select in `indicator-cpufreq` applet `Performance` (for best performance), then checked via `lscpu` it is working.

```
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
CPU MHz:             3455.159
CPU max MHz:         3500,0000
CPU min MHz:         400,0000
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

Then I ran Bitwig studio. I tried do load some my older project.

**Issue**

When play the music in DAW, there are some crackling during the playing, and when I do something in DAW during playing (for example zooming or moving only), crackling is even worst.

Jackd log shows me many `xruns`.

I swear I had same configuration before reinstall OS and it was OK for this configuration, no crackling at all during playing even when working in DAW during playing or recording.

I tried install older versions of `Ubuntu studio`, no effect, crackling still present, same.

Why is now crackling due playing in DAW? Applet `indicator-cpufreq` changed to best performance, but seems not for DAW, no effect for `CPU load` in DAW when I selecting between `Performance` and `Powersave` in `indicator-cpufreq`, but `lscpu` shows me different `CPU MHz`.

What is the magic? Before I reinstalled OS, everything works fine. I found something about `nice` utility. Is it what I need to setup?

Thank you very much for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I did to get best performance after fresh Ubuntu install.
> Priority set is important.
>
> Install low latency kernel.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-lowlatency
> ```
>
> Add new lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf
>
> * - rtprio 70
> * - memlock unlimited
> * hard memlock unlimited
> * soft memlock unlimited
> ```
>
> Install some services to set CPU for best performance.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install cpufrequtils
> sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq
> ```
>
> (after reboot you will see applet in notification area for changing
> performance of CPU)
>
> Reboot.
>
> Install `jackd2` if you don't have installed already.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install jackd2
> ```
>
> Get name of your hardware. For example, my hardware: is `PCH`. The
> name of the hardware is in `[]`.
>
> ```
> cat /proc/asound/cards
>
>  0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
>                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1228000 irq 130
> ```
>
> Run jackd2 with parameters you need.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/jackd -d alsa -d hw:PCH -r 48000 -p 192 -n 3
> ```
>
> You can change periods `-p`, frames `-n` and sample rate `-r`
> parameter for lowest latency. If crackling is present, this is your
> limit. `(Frames / Sample Rate ) * Periods = Latency in ms`.
>
> Run DAW.
>
> That's all. I hope this info could be helpful.

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1165374/2).</sup>